# Decompile the apk

Tags: android, project, recovery, decompiler

I was building an Android project that cleared my code and recovery didn't succeed, so I decided to recreate the project. And to speed up my work, I decided to get tested apk code (not built just run in the emulator). 
Is there any way to do this?

I analyzed the software from device explorer ->(data / app / App Package) but didn't display the code and res

image ( https://a.imge.to/2019/08/09/Q893O.png ) of android studio

Comment: Use apktool to reverse apk https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/ and get your all assets/res

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First pull your apk from device using `adb` command. `adb shell pm path com.example` where `com.example` your `package name` (`applicationId`). This will show your apk location. Then run `adb pull /path/to/apk/location` replace /path/to/apk/location with real path. This will copy apk file. Then use `jadx` and `apktool` to decompile your apk.